# Why does 10101 | 11100 return 12157 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

How come when I do:
10101 | 11100 I get 12157?
I want to just compare the bits to get 11101.

Comment: `10101` is ten thousands one hundred and one. Its binary representation as an integer number is `10011101110101` (padded to the left with `0` up to 32 bits). Similar for `11100`. The result is correct, your expectations are incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the operation with decimal integers. You probably want to use binary values. In the example you provided:

```js
const value = 0b10101 | 0b11100;
console.log(value);
```

Comment: So I can use 0b to indicate it is a binary value. I didn't know that.